# chi square distribution as a function of other variables

Tags: confidence-interval, matlab, numerics, chi-squared-distribution

I'm minimizing $\chi^2$ between some data and a function. The expression $\chi^2 = \sum\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}(y_i-f(A,B))^2$ happens to be analytically solvable, so I have a value for the minimum $\chi^2$, which I'll call $\chi^2_0$, and I have an expression for $\chi^2$ in terms of the parameters $A,B: \chi^2(A,B)$.

Now I'd like to plug $\chi^2(A,B)$ into the expression for the chi square distribution, so that I can integrate in the A,B parameter space to get a 90% confidence interval.

In other words, I'd like to integrate 
$ \frac{\chi(A,B)^{(n-2)/2}e^{-\chi(A,B)/2}}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)} $, where $n$ is the number of degrees of freedom, over some area in the A,B plane, until my integral reaches 0.9. This is how I will define my 90% confidence limit in A,B. In my case, n=800.

The problem is that I'm doing this in Matlab, and $\Gamma(n/2)$ evaluates to infinity, as does $\chi(A,B)^{n/2-1}$. The factor of $\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}$ would balance this out analytically but numerically I am running into problems.

I'm wondering if I am approaching this the wrong way, or, if not, if there's something I can do to my code to get this to work.

Comment: Leaving aside any other considerations, the numerical issue could be dealt with by working on the log scale.

Comment: @Glen_b that seems like a good suggestion, but I'm not sure how to transform back from log space after taking an integral. I need to integrate the $\chi^2$ function in polar coordinates. I just tried to work out the transformation back from log space after integrating but I got stuck.

Comment: I mean "work with the log of each term, combining them on the log scale (i.e. multiplication becomes addition of logs, division becomes a difference of logs etc), and only exponentiate at the end" in order to avoid getting underflow or overflow in the numerator or denominator.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm sorry but I genuinely don't understand how I can take the integral of the log of a function then transform back to the integral of the original function. I can ignore the denominator and normalize that out later, but the numerator still evaluates to INF*0 for the values I'm working with in the region I want to integrate over. Since I need to integrate the function I genuinely don't understand the suggestion. Sorry.

Comment: "*don't understand how I can take the integral of the log of a function then transform back to the integral of the original function*". You don't. Note that "at the end" is "just before computing the integral".